# CRM 2011 : All workflows firing simultaneously on save instead of record status change

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a CRM 2011 workflow and it should fire on change of one field, I have selected my field in ‘Record fields change’, but everytime i save all the workflows relating to that entity get fired. I am not understanding why all the workflows are firing for all the field changes.

Please let me know if anybody has any ideas.

Comment: How are you attempting to save the record, through the UI or through the SDK?

Comment: @Daryl saving the record through SDK (in javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code I'd have to take a guess here, but 9 times out of 10 it's due to you submitting more fields than you actually need to in the SDK.

When using the CRM SDK, don't ever perform updates by performing a select, which returns back more fields than what you are planning to update. Any fields in the attribute collection of the Entity will be updated even if they haven't changed. Instead, instantiate a new entity locally, set the id and whatever attributes you want to update and update it.